# Why must both series of a Cauchy product be absoloutley convergent for the Cauchy product converge absoloutley?

Tags: real-analysis

I'm looking at a theorem that states if $\sum a_n$ and $\sum b_n$ are absolutely convergent then the Cauchy product $\sum c_n$ is absolutely convergent. Where $c_n = \sum_{j=0}^{n} a_j b_{n-j}$. I came up with this proof which is either 1) wrong because it doesn't use the fact that both series converge absolutely or 2) uses the fact that both series (particularly series $b_n$) converge absolutely without me noticing it. I have seen other similar posts such as [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/202467/cauchy-product-of-two-absolutely-convergent-series-is-absolutely-convergent-ru) but my question is about the following process specifically and looking at the previous posts I still can't tell if the problem is 1) or 2). I write this post in the hopes that someone will point out which one it is. Here is my proof:

Compute:

$$ \left|\sum_{n=0}^{M} |c_n| - \sum_{n=0}^{K} |c_n|\right|$$

Without loss of generality we can assume that $M \geq K$:

$$= \left|\sum_{n=K}^{M} |c_n| \right|=\sum_{n=K}^{M} |c_n|$$

Rewrite $c_n$:

$$=\sum_{n=K}^{M} |a_n B_{M-n}|$$

If $\sum b_n$ converges to $B$ and $B_M$ is the $M$'th partial sum of $b_n$ then:

$$=\sum_{n=K}^{M} |a_n (B_{M-n}-B+B)|$$

By the triangle inequality:

$$\leq \sum_{n=K}^{M} |a_n (B_{M-n}-B)| + \sum_{n=K}^{M} |a_n B|=\sum_{n=K}^{M} |a_n| |B_{M-n}-B| + \sum_{n=K}^{M} |a_n B|$$

Consider the set $\{|B_n - B| : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ since $B_n$ converges then this set is bounded. Let $B_{MAX} = sup\{|B_n - B| : n \in \mathbb{N}\} $ then:

$$\leq B_{MAX} \sum_{n=K}^{M} |a_n| + |B| \sum_{n=K}^{M} |a_n| = (B_{MAX}+|B|) \sum_{n=K}^{M} |a_n|$$

Take $K$ large enough so $\sum_{n=K}^{M} |a_n| < \epsilon/{(B_{MAX}+|B|)}$ (which must exists since $a_n$ converges absolutely) to conclude:

$$\left |\sum_{n=0}^{M} |c_n| - \sum_{n=0}^{K} |c_n| \right|<\epsilon$$

Thus, $|c_n|$ is Cauchy and thus, $c_n$ converges absolutely.

QED?

Comment: I did not check your proof, but the Cauchy product of an absolute convergent series with a conditionally convergent series may fail to converge absolutely. Examples are given here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2272433/42969

Comment: @MartinR thank you for providing this counter example. I know that this can happen and that's why I say that the proof must either be wrong or using the fact of absolute convergence without me noticing it. I have replaced these in the proof and replicated the process and I somehow get to them converging absolutely.

Comment: I think you use the wrong $\sum |c_n|$ since when you take the absolute value of the individual $c_n$ and add them, the $b$'s are inside each such, so to combine them in $B_n$ means that they have to go outside the absolute value so they get to be $|b_n|$

Comment: @Conrad thank you for your interest. I'm not entirely sure what you mean, could you please elaborate further? If it is the substitution $c_n = a_n B_{M-n}$ I am rather confident that is correct as I have seen it use multiple times. I could post a proof of it if it where necessary.

Comment: It is not correct that $c_n=a_nB_{M-n}$ - see definition of $c_n$; what is correct is that sum of $c_n$ is indeed a sum of the $a_nB_{M-n}$ by grouping terms  with same $a$

Comment: Part-way through the question you switch from $b_i$ to $B_i$ -- can you fix this?

Comment: @Conrad, Thank you! You are correct, it is the sum, not the terms.

Comment: @JBL not sure what you mean by $b_i$ but $B_i$ is just the $i$'th partial sum of $b_n$

Comment: I see, thanks -- that doesn't seem to be explained in the question anywhere (?)

Comment: Hopefully now is clear where the mistake is and how indeed the absolute convergence of $b_n$ is implicitly used since you actually need the sums of $|b_n|$ not $B_n$ for your argument to work

Comment: @JBL thanks, I have updated the OP for clarity.

Comment: @Conrad it is, thank you. A couple triangle inequalities later and I have the correct proof now.

Comment: @ja.ortiz: It's not quite clear to me from your comments what the status of your question is. If it's been answered, you could ideally write up the answer and accept it so that the question doesn't linger unanswered. Alternatively you could delete the question. In any case, in its current form, the question doesn't seem to reflect the fact that you "have the correct proof now".

Comment: @joriki I do have the answer, the process is basically the same except the substitution of the partial sums is not done with an equal but with a $\leq$ when $b_n$ converges absolutely. I don't see why the question should reflect that I have the correct answer or why I should prove that I do. Further, I do not wish to provide the correct answer as this is part of a problem set for a course and posting it's answers online would undermine the ability to evaluate the comprehension of future students. What I have learned from Conrad was enough for me to realize my mistake and get a correct answer.